# Threat service has stopped

Tags: windows

Please can any one tell I can not get an other option where I set the value [image]

Answer (score -1):

An option may be in Policy folder

Comment: Not in that folder also

Comment: I tried to help you. But why did you Downvoted the post? I am new here & you also. Please be good. Thanks.